# Kafka Consumer Rebalancing Algorithm

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can someone please tell me what the rebalancing algorithm is for Kafka consumers? I would like to understand how partition count and consumer threads affect this.

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kafka Consumer Rebalancing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181693/kafka-consumer-rebalancing)

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thank you for the input, however that doesn't cover the algorithm in the detail I was looking for, as currently with Kafka 0.8 we see some strange behavior, and I need to understand the algorithm to properly account for this.

Comment: You should add that information to your question, then ;) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26757733/899126) one might help a little more

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok so there are 2 rebalancing algorithms at the moment - `Range` and `RoundRobin`. They are also called Partition Assignment Strategies.

For the simplicity assume we have a topic `T1` with 10 partitions and we also have 2 consumers with different configurations (for the example to be clearer) - `C1` with `num.streams` set to `1` and `C2` with `num.streams` set to `2`.

Here's how that would work with `Range` strategy:

Range lays out available partitions in numeric order and consumer threads in lexicographic order. So in our case the order of partitions will be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` and order of consumer threads will be `C1-0, C2-0, C2-1`. Then the number of partitions is divided by the number of consumer threads to determine how many partitions each consumer thread should own. In our case it doesn't divide equally, so the thread `C1-0` will get one extra partition. The final partition assignment would look like this:

`C1-0` gets partitions `0, 1, 2, 3`
`C2-0` gets partitions `4, 5, 6`
`C2-1` gets partitions `7, 8, 9`

If there would be 11 partitions the partition assignment for these consumers would change a bit:

`C1-0` would get partitions `0, 1, 2, 3`
`C2-0` would get partitions `4, 5, 6, 7`
`C2-1` would get partitions `8, 9, 10`

That's it.

The same configuration wouldn't work for `RoundRobin` strategy as it requires equal `num.streams` across all consumers subscribed for this topic, so lets assume both consumers have `num.streams` set to 2 now. One major difference compared to `Range` strategy here is that you cannot predict what the assignment will be prior to rebalance. Here's how that would work with `RoundRobin` strategy:

First, there are 2 conditions that MUST be satisfied before actual assignment:

a) Every topic has the same number of streams within a consumer instance (that's why I mentioned above that different number of threads per consumer will not work)
b) The set of subscribed topics is identical for every consumer instance within the group (we have one topic here so that's not a problem now).

When these 2 conditions are verified the `topic-partition` pairs are sorted by hashcode to reduce the possibility of all partitions of one topic to be assigned to one consumer (if there is more than one topic to be consumed).

And finally, all `topic-partition` pairs are assigned in a round-robin fashion to available consumer threads. For example if our topic-partitions will end up sorted like this: `T1-5, T1-3, T1-0, T1-8, T1-2, T1-1, T1-4, T1-7, T1-6, T1-9` and consumer threads are `C1-0, C1-1, C2-0, C2-1` then the assignment will be like this:

`T1-5` goes to `C1-0`
`T1-3` goes to `C1-1`
`T1-0` goes to `C2-0`
`T1-8` goes to `C2-1`
At this point no more consumer threads are left, but there are still more topic-partitions, so iteration over consumer threads starts over:
`T1-2` goes to `C1-0`
`T1-1` goes to `C1-1`
`T1-4` goes to `C2-0`
`T1-7` goes to `C2-1`
And again:
`T1-6` goes to `C1-0`
`T1-9` goes to `C1-1`

At this point all topic-partitions are assigned and each consumer thread has near-equal number of partitions each.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if there are more consumer threads than partitions?

Comment: @Kousha then some consumer threads will be idle an won't get any partition.

Comment: It seems like round-robin would make search each consumer got some data, but not necessarily all threads.

Comment: Range seems like it would just fill up the threads in the first few consumers, possibly leaving full consumers without any partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not fully understand why there are two restrictions for RoundRobin, could you please give more explanation?

Comment: @shizhz I actually don't have an answer for your question, but javadoc for RoundRobinAssignor says `(For simplicity of implementation) the assignor is allowed to assign a given topic-partition to any consumer instance and thread-id within that instance`

Comment: @serejja I have similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072666/how-to-run-multiple-kafka-consumers-on-the-same-box-independent-of-each-other) related to Kafka where I am running multiple consumers on the same box. I wanted to see if my design looks right or there can be any  improvements?

Answer (score 2):

You could read this Kafka docs http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_brokerregistration about Consumer registration algorithm and Consumer rebalancing algorithm

As it said, each consumer does the following during rebalancing :

```
1. For each topic T that C<sub>i</sub> subscribes to
2.   let P<sub>T</sub> be all partitions producing topic T
3.   let C<sub>G</sub> be all consumers in the same group as C<sub>i</sub> that consume topic T
4.   sort P<sub>T</sub> (so partitions on the same broker are clustered together)
5.   sort C<sub>G</sub>
6.   let i be the index position of C<sub>i</sub> in C<sub>G</sub> and let N = size(P<sub>T</sub>)/size(C<sub>G</sub>)
7.   assign partitions from i*N to (i+1)*N - 1 to consumer C<sub>i</sub>
8.   remove current entries owned by C<sub>i</sub> from the partition owner registry
9.   add newly assigned partitions to the partition owner registry
    (we may need to re-try this until the original partition owner releases its ownership)
```

And also Notice that:

> If there are more consumers than partitions, some consumers won't get any data at all. During rebalancing, we try to assign partitions to consumers in such a way that reduces the number of broker nodes each consumer has to connect to.