# Kafka: Which consumer will get the message if there are many consumers that subscribe one topic with the same group-id?

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

Supposing we have 4 consumers with the same `group-id` and one topic including 3 partitions. If a producer post a message to partition-1, then which consumer will get this message?

Comment: First, the fourth consumer in your example will do nothing because if the number of consumers is greater than the number of partitions some consumers will be idle and will get no partitions to consume. Second, please see this answer on how rebalancing works -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574054/kafka-consumer-rebalancing-algorithm/28580363#28580363

Comment: @serejja Thank you, you could answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a bit more detailed answer here.

So the first point is that there is no reason to have more consumer threads (and each consumer has at least 1 consumer thread) than the number of partitions being consumed. The reason is that if you have more consumer threads than partitions, some consumer threads will just end up being idle and will just waste resources. So given the example you attached there is no point of having 4 consumers for 3 partitions.

The second point - the partition assignment depends on the strategy chosen by consumers in the group. Currently there are 2 partition assignment strategies - `Range` and `RoundRobin`. If you are using the `Range` strategy you can predict what partitions will be consumed by each consumer after rebalance. With `RoundRobin` strategy though you can't predict beforehand the partition assignments for consumers after rebalance.

The detailed answer that explains how consumer rebalancing works and how partitions are assigned is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574054/kafka-consumer-rebalancing-algorithm/28580363#28580363).

You can also view current partition assignments for your consumer group in Zookeeper at `/consumers/[group_id]/owners/[topic]/[partition]`